# I'm trying to set a class name on <a> tag. the problem is when I click on the link the page refreshes and the class is removed

Tags: javascript, html, ajax, laravel-6

I have the following HTML piece of code

```
<li>
    <a href="javascript:;"><i class="sidebar-item-icon ti-hummer"></i>
        <span class="nav-label">Product Management</span><i class="fa fa-angle-left arrow"></i></a>
    <ul class="nav-2-level collapse">
        <li>
            <a href="/admin/addProducts" id="addProductMenu" onclick="addActiveClass(this)" >Add Product</a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="/admin/allProducts" id="allProductsMenu" onclick="addActiveClass(this)">All Products</a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="/admin/recommendedProducts" id="recommendedMenu" onclick="addActiveClass(this)">Recommended</a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="/admin/featuredProducts" id="featuredMenu" onclick="addActiveClass(this)">Featured</a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="/admin/bestSellingProducts" id="bestSellingMenu" onclick="addActiveClass(this)">Best Selling</a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="/admin/popularIndustriesProducts" id="popularIndustriesMenu" onclick="addActiveClass(this)">Under popular industries</a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</li>
```

what I want is when I click on any of the `<a>` link, the javascript function `addActiveClass(this)` is called and add a class `class='active'` on the clicked `<a>` tag.

The javascript code is

```
function addActiveClass(element) {
    var el = document.getElementById(element.id);
    el.classList.add("active");
    el.parentElement.classList.add("active");
}
```

My problem is that when I click on the link the javascript function is executed and the class gets applied. Then after that, the page refreshes and since the class was added dynamically, after re-loading the page, the previously added class `class='active'` is removed.

How should I make the class get set after a refresh?

These lists are on the static page that loads child pages which changes.

Comment: When you click on a link it navigates to the URL in the link.

Comment: Why are you getting the ID of the element and then looking it up by ID? Just do `var el = element;`

Comment: Seems like you want to have an active link highlighted when user is on the page which link represents. So it’s better to watch location on page load and then highlight a link with the same href as ‘window.location’

Answer (score 1):

Thanks *heleg* for your suggestion it actually worked,

I did the following

```
$(document).ready(function() {

var path = window.location.pathname.split("/").pop();
var parent = null;
var activeElement = null;
var target = null;

if (path == "") {
    path = "home";
}

if (path == "home") {
    target = $('nav div ul li a[href="/admin/' + path + '"]');
} else {
    target = $('nav div ul li ul li a[href="/admin/' + path + '"]');
}

target.addClass("active");

if (path != "home") {
    activeElement = document.getElementsByClassName("active");

    parent = activeElement[0].parentElement;

    parent = parent.parentElement;

    parent.classList.add("in");

    parent = parent.parentElement;

    parent.classList.add("active");
}
});
```

Answer (score 0):

For onclick to work on an anchor tag, you need to stop the default action of an  tag on clicking as by default anchor tags navigate to the URL in the link.
You can instead write,

```
function addActiveClass(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    let el = document.getElementById(e.target.id);
    el.classList.add("active");
    el.parentElement.classList.add("active");
}
```

Comment: It looks like preventDefault() is not preventing the default action as it still navigates to a page.